# Corrupting the heap while writing an object to a binary file

Tags: c++, arrays, binaryfiles, fstream

I have this class with a constructor and destructor

```
class Monster
{
    char* nume;
    double hp;
    float* dmgAbilitati;
    int nrAbilitati;

public:

    Monster(const char* nume, double hp, int nrAbilitati, float* dmgAbilitati)
    {
        if (nume == nullptr)
            throw new exception("Nume invalid!\n");
        else
        {
            this->nume = new char[strlen(nume) + 1];
            strcpy_s(this->nume, strlen(nume) + 1, nume);
        }
        if (hp <= 0)
            throw new exception("Hp invalid!\n");
        else
            this->hp = hp;
        if (nrAbilitati <= 0 && dmgAbilitati == nullptr)
            throw new exception("nrAbilitati invalid sau dmgAbilitati invalid!\n");
        else
        {
            this->nrAbilitati = nrAbilitati;
            this->dmgAbilitati = new float[nrAbilitati];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrAbilitati; i++)
                this->dmgAbilitati[i] = dmgAbilitati[i];
        }
    }

    ~Monster()
    {
        if (this->nume != nullptr)
            delete[] this->nume;
        if (this->dmgAbilitati != nullptr)
            delete[] this->dmgAbilitati;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to write and read a Monster object to/from a binary file using these 2 functions

```
void scriereFisierBinar(ofstream& fisBinarOut)
    {
        int dim = strlen(nume) + 1;
        fisBinarOut.write((char*)&dim, sizeof(dim));
        fisBinarOut.write(this->nume, dim);

        fisBinarOut.write((char*)&this->hp, sizeof(this->hp));
        fisBinarOut.write((char*)&this->nrAbilitati, sizeof(this->nrAbilitati));

        for (int i = 0; i < this->nrAbilitati; i++)
            fisBinarOut.write((char*)(&this->dmgAbilitati[i]), sizeof(this->dmgAbilitati[i]));
    }

    void citireFisierBinar(ifstream& fisBinarIn)
    {
        int dim = 0;
        char aux[100];
        fisBinarIn.read((char*)&dim, sizeof(dim));

        fisBinarIn.read(aux, dim);
        if (nume != nullptr)
            delete[] nume;

        this->nume = new char[dim];
        strcpy_s(this->nume, dim, aux);

        fisBinarIn.read((char*)&this->hp, sizeof(this->hp));
        fisBinarIn.read((char*)&this->nrAbilitati, sizeof(this->nrAbilitati));

        for (int i = 0; i < this->nrAbilitati; i++)
            fisBinarIn.read((char*)(&this->dmgAbilitati[i]), sizeof(this->dmgAbilitati[i]));
        
    }
```

In main i have this:

```
float vvv[] = { 44,432,366,433,511 };
    Monster TEST000("Sper", 6969, 5, vvv);

    ofstream fisBinarOut("tt.bin", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
    if (fisBinarOut.is_open())
    {
        TEST000.scriereFisierBinar(fisBinarOut);
        fisBinarOut.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "No!\n";

    float vvvv[] = { 1 };
    Monster mm("Nu", 3123, 1, vvvv);

    ifstream fisBinarIn("tt.bin", ios::in, ios::binary);
    if (fisBinarIn.is_open())
    {
        mm.citireFisierBinar(fisBinarIn);
        cout << mm;
        fisBinarIn.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "No\n";
```

I want the 'mm' object to have the attributes of 'TEST000', but only the name and Hp change plus I receive a heap error : "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory." So i am guessing that the array implementation is wrong.
I have attached a picture of the error along with the results. Using `char*` is mandatory for this project. It also throws an exception to the destructor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRGGq.jpg

Comment: This code reminds me why I love `std::string` and `std::vector`

Comment: 1) Can you post a minimal reproducible example? 2) At `citireFisierBinar`, shouldn't you be freeing the `hp` buffer before overwriting it, as you do with `nume`? That should be a heap memory leak, though, and not the cause of the corruption. 3) I would carefully check for out of bounds accesses. Have you tried debugging the program (clicking Retry on that error window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `citireFisierBinar`: while there is a reallocation for the `nume` array member, there is no reallocation (or at least check for sufficient memory) for the `dmgAbilitati` array member.

There are some other isuues in your code, for example:

- Throwing exceptions: ctor code throws a pointer; it should throw a non-pointer value instead.
- It provides *no exception guarantee*: if new memory can't be allocated, `bad_alloc` exception will be thrown and the object will not be in a valid state. For example, the memory for `numa` is deallocated in `citireFisierBinar`, so how do you think, what would happen in destructor. Or in ctor, if an exception is thrown (because of invalid arg) your object can be like "half-constructed" and the memory is leaked.

Theese are the major issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).